# Given a list, how to map the second value of each element from that list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Given a list, lets say `[("@elBarto", "yo no fui"), ("@krusty", "yo tampoco"), ("@pedro", "tal vez")]`
, I need a function that get the second value of each element from that list  `["yo no fui", "yo tampoco", "tal vez"]`.
From what I can tell, the list contains tuples so I can use snd from each one. The return is should be a mapped list but I can't get how to do it, maybe something like map snd from each tuple..

Comment: `maybe something like map snd from each tuple` - did you try what you have suggested?

Comment: If you want to try it again but this time without help you can try to get the same result using list-comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just `map snd yourList`:

```
> map snd [("@elBarto", "yo no fui"), ("@krusty", "yo tampoco"), ("@pedro", "tal vez")]
["yo no fui","yo tampoco","tal vez"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot chepner, this worked 'textos = map snd' since the list was coming as parameter. Can I ask you, if you dont mind, the firm of that function? 'textos:: [a] ->

Comment: You know more about the input than that it is a list of some unknown type; you know that it's a list of *tuples*. `textos :: [(a,b)] -> [b]`. You can see that by running `:t map snd` in GHCi.